# Combine lists in R

Tags: r, list, data-structures, lapply, mclapply

What would be an easy and fast way to get from:

```
x <- list(a1=2, b1=c(1,2), c1=1:3)
y <- list(a2=5, b2=c(2,5), c2=2:4)
```

to

```
list(list(x$a1, y$a2), list(x$b1, y$b2), list(x$c1, y$c2))
```

?

Or in general:

If list x and y have same length and their elements also correspond in length,
how can it be combined to a single list as shown above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way would be to use `mapply` as follows:

```
mapply(x, y, FUN=list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Not sure if it's the fastest though. You can replace `x` and `y` with `unname(x)` and `unname(y)` if you don't want names in your output.